# How to slow down time for an entire virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, microsoft-virtual-pc

Is there a way to slow down virtual machine, and I don't mean limiting cpu resources, or such
but a real simulated slow down, which would also slow down system time so each virtual millisecond in vm would take preselected amount of real time milliseconds (e.g. 1 msec in vm would last 10 msec real time)

Comment: What would be the end goal for this?

Comment: At which point should it exactly slow down? before/at boot?

Comment: research into effects of time variance and how it might affect hardware, operating systems and software. ideally on the fly changes using slider/input box, but if nothing else even static value before or at boot time would be helpful

Comment: Are you planning to place one computer in a temporal anomaly or something? Last I checked time runs at the same speed everywhere. If you are wondering what what happens if the clocks between two PC's are different, I suggest setting the time manually?

Answer (score 3):

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) has a built in feature for this that you can run through VBoxManage, if you want to double the speed, browse to your VirtualBox folder from command prompt and run:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/TM/WarpDrivePercentage" 200
```

Likewise, if you want to set the speed to 10%:

```
VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" "VBoxInternal/TM/WarpDrivePercentage" 10
```

Note that you should turn off any clock syncing mechanism such as NTP if you do this.

Source: [Virtualbox Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#warpguest)

Comment: Just the fact that it's called `WarpDrivePercentage` says something about who'd want to use this... `:)`

Comment: Now I really want to try this and just see what happens...